# How to display formatted Calendar type in JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am using Calendar type in Java and I would like to display formatted date in JSTL.

I was trying:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<fmt:parseDate var="date" type="date" dateStyle="short" value="${photo.dateCreated}" />
<c:out value="${data}" />
```

But it doesn't work:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Can JSTL format `Calendar` type?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it can only format the [`java.util.Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) type since it uses [`DateFormat#format()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.lang.Date%29) under the hoods. Use [`Calendar#getTime()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) to grab it from the `Calendar`.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${photo.dateCreated.time}" type="date" dateStyle="short" />
```

Note that you need `fmt:formatDate` for this, not `fmt:parseDate`. Formatting is converting a `Date` object into a human readable date string and parsing is converting a human readable date string into a `Date` object.

Comment: Don't forget the taglib definition for fmt `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`

Comment: @disrvptor: OP already had it, otherwise he wouldn't have gotten a `ParseException`.

Comment: Ok, it just wasn't apparent in the response or question.  I see `c` and `fn`, but not `fmt`